# Select current date on calendar with javascript and html

Tags: javascript

I created a simple calendar with html and now want the current date to highlight automatically with javascript.  I know of a few ways to do this but I am looking for the most simple.

Comment: I've added an additional solution where you don't need to code the ids, which will save a good amount of HTML being passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how your calendar works.  You can get the client's current date with the following JavaScript:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

Once you have that, you'll have to use the built in [date functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to get the current date element and probably add a class to it that will style it as highlighted.

**UPDATE**

Assuming you have your `li` elements with `id="dayElement_x"` where `x` is the day number, and your class for highlighting your day is `currentDay`, an example JavaScript call would be:

```
document.getElementById('dayElement_' + (new Date()).getDate()).className += ' currentDay';
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just thought of a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/Avumf/4/) where you can do this without having a bunch of ids.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('calendarContainer').
    getElementsByTagName('li')[(new Date()).getDate() - 1].className += ' currentDate';
```

Comment: Okay say that I have a list of numbers 1 - 30.  I want the number highlighted based on the current day of the month. I am not sure the best way to do that with the date function.

Comment: @zach: [getDate](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) will give you the number between 1-31 of the day of the month.

Comment: Yes I have that part.  So far I have var d = new Date();
document.write(d.getDate()); ...  Now I am trying to figure out the code that will highlight the correct <li> based on the var d number.

Comment: @zach: For each of your calendar elements in the HTML, I would give them an id that includes the day number for that month, such as `id="dayElement_1"`.  Then, I would get this element by `document.getElementById('dayElement_' + (new Date()).getDate())` and set it's className appropriately.

Comment: Okay this is making sense now.  Can you check out what I have so far and give me a suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/Avumf/

Comment: @zach: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/Avumf/3/) an updated fiddle that set's it bold.